# Mod-rewrite not working centos

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, vps

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.am [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.am/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Why is it not working,I added that in the /etc/httpd/conf/http.conf in the end, I made sure

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html">
```

Is it because my site is in /srv/www/domain/public_html?

Comment: is your site www.example.am, and defined as such in its vhost definition?

Comment: No i took my url out but i had my url previously it still didn't work?

Comment: Maybe mod_rewrite isn't loaded? Don't use IfModule like this!

Answer (score -1):

Move the Mod rewrite code to a .htaccess file in the root of the webserver (i.e. The /srv/www/domain/public_html server)

Restart the Apache service (or nginx depending on what server you are using) and that should apply the mod-rewrite to your site.